Question preview MathJax error
When I search this, I get this answer preview:

However, there is a dollar sign after the V=L in the post:

I believe the main problem with $V=L$ is how it restricts reflection.

Is this intended or a bug?

Some related posts on other sites:
Search results and MathJax,
MathJax tripped for some reason on the search page,
Search renders MathJax sections incorrectly,
MathJax rendering broken in previews from search and
MathJax rendering in snippets confused by search terms.

I doubt it's intended...

StackExchange highlights your search term by putting it in bold (using <b>...</b> tags).  In your case, that means the answer contains $<b>V=L</b>$.  But MathJax won't process math that contains HTML tags (the mat must be only text), and so does not see these two dollar signs as math delimiters.  In this case, the final one turns out to be considered the start delimiter matching a later dollar sign, and so everything in between (up to the next bold "V") is rendered as mathematics, so in italics.
That is, the opening and closing delimiters are getting misinterpreted, due to the bold tags that have been inserted in the math.
I doubt there is a reasonable solution to this, as the search algorithm would have to be much smarter in order to properly insert bold into the mathematics to avoid this problem.
